# Übersetzung für "Fusselst Du?"

Tags: translation

Ich habe heute im Internet Folgendes gesehen:

[image: Fusselst du?]

und dachte: ehh?  Im Wörterbuch konnte ich 'fusseln' nicht finden.  Kann mir jemand mit einer Übersetzung helfen?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ein "Fussel" ist ein [fluff](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=fussel), fuzz. "Fusseln" ist das dazugehörige Verb. Eine Sache, die Fussel erzeugt oder verstreut "fusselt".

Konjugation:

- Ich fussel (oder Ich fussele - dürfte eher süddeutsch sein)
- Du fusselst
- Er/Sie/Es fusselt
- Wir fusseln
- Ihr fusselt
- Sie fusseln

Comment: Ach, jetzt verstehe ich.  Danke!

Comment: @Glen: Man könnte ergänzen, dass _normalerweise_ nur "es fusselt" verwendet wird. "Du fusselst" ist per se schon komisch. (Du könntest es z.B. zu Deiner Katze sagen `:-)`)

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: Katzen fusseln nicht, sie haaren. Das ist ein Unterschied. Du kling für mich übrigen überhaupt nicht komisch. Wobei damit natürlich gemeint ist: Deine Kleidung fusselt.

Comment: @raznagul: Du hast natürlich recht, Katzen haaren und fusseln nicht. Deshalb auch der Smiley `:-)` Noch nachgefragt: Meintest Du, "Du fusselst" ist als Kurzform für "Deine Kleidung fusselt" zu verstehen? Das klingt für mich ähnlich lustig wie "Du fusselst" zu meiner Katze, da ja eben nicht der Mensch fusselt (lustig im positiven Sinne!).

Answer (score 5):

According to [dict.leo.org](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=en&search=fussel) the noun "Fussel" translates to "fluff", "fluzz" or "lint". The verb means to leave (or maybe shed?) fluff.

Answer (score 2):

*[To pill](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pill#Verb)*, as in what sweaters do when they get those little balls all over them.

Comment: I don't think that pilling is the relevant behaviour here: Why would the bear be concerned with that?

Answer (score 0):

Fussel → Fluse.

The question is if the rabbit's pelt contains fluses.